Error caused in a C to Assembly Assignment
My MIPS code follows:
##
## Place your header here
## including purpose of the program
##
.text
main:
# Prompt for the integer to enter
li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt
syscall

# Read the integer and save it in $s0
li $v0, 5
syscall
move $s0, $v0

# Output the text
li $v0, 4
la $a0, output
syscall

# Output the number
li $v0, 1
move $a0, $s0
syscall

# Exit the program
li $v0, 10
syscall

.data
prompt: .asciiz "Please enter an integer: "
output: .asciiz "\nYou typed the number "

I'm trying to run an assembly code onto QTSPIM and it keeps popping up with the error:
spim: (parser) syntax error on line 8 of file
      /Users/somebody/Desktop/Lesson6AssemblyExercise.asm
      li $v0, 4
         ^

Image of the error dialog also shown for completeness:

I changed my preferences as instructed by a professor (see below) but I'm not too sure what the problem is. I'm wondering if someone can tell me what it could be?

This code was given to us in a form that should just run but I cannot get it to do so.

Please [edit] your question to show all error messages as text.  Images should only be used if text doesn't suffice.

Thank you it actually worked and accepted the code.

@fuz, I brought the images into the question so as to make it more self-contained. Probably not worth making the error textual since it's relatively simple to read as-is, but I'll do that as well, just to be sure.

@paxdiablo Errors as text means the error message is accessible to blind users and is indexed by search engines.  Both improve the usefulness of this question significantly.

You need to enable pseudo instructions, something you haven't done based on your first graphic:


The reason is that MIPS has a set of real instructions, and relies on an assembler to provide translations of pseudo instructions into something from the real instruction set. More information can be found here.
For example, your specific pseudo-instruction li $v0, 4 may be translated into a real instruction such as:
ori $v0, $zero, 4  ; v0 <- 0 or 4

Keep in mind that's only one translation possibility. It could also become a different instruction, provided it gave the same functional result.
For example, the QtSpim user manual dated November 15, 2013, section 4.2 Pseudo-Instructions, has this to say (slightly paraphrased for readability):

QtSpim can also interpret what are called pseudo instructions. These are instructions that are written by the program writer to perform a specific purpose not necessarily supported by the MIPS ISA. These instructions are translated by QtSpim into native instructions.
For example li (load immediate) loads a value directly into a given register. QtSpim simply translates this instruction into an add immediate instruction that adds the given immediate value to the zero register. In other words, li $1, 4 becomes addi $1, $0, 4.

And, in fact, once you get it loading properly, you can see the translations in the user text segment window, as called out below:
[00400000] 8fa40000  lw $4, 0($29)            ; 183: lw $a0 0($sp) # argc 
[00400004] 27a50004  addiu $5, $29, 4         ; 184: addiu $a1 $sp 4 # argv 
[00400008] 24a60004  addiu $6, $5, 4          ; 185: addiu $a2 $a1 4 # envp 
[0040000c] 00041080  sll $2, $4, 2            ; 186: sll $v0 $a0 2 
[00400010] 00c23021  addu $6, $6, $2          ; 187: addu $a2 $a2 $v0 
[00400014] 0c100009  jal 0x00400024 [main]    ; 188: jal main 
[00400018] 00000000  nop                      ; 189: nop 
[0040001c] 3402000a  ori $2, $0, 10           ; 191: li $v0 10 
[00400020] 0000000c  syscall                  ; 192: syscall # syscall 10 (exit) 
                     vvvvvvvvvvvvv                 vvvvvvvvv
[00400024] 34020004  ori $2, $0, 4            ; 8: li $v0, 4 
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^                 ^^^^^^^^^
[00400028] 3c011001  lui $1, 4097 [prompt]    ; 9: la $a0, prompt 
[0040002c] 34240000  ori $4, $1, 0 [prompt]   
[00400030] 0000000c  syscall                  ; 10: syscall 
[00400034] 34020005  ori $2, $0, 5            ; 13: li $v0, 5 
[00400038] 0000000c  syscall                  ; 14: syscall 
[0040003c] 00028021  addu $16, $0, $2         ; 15: move $s0, $v0 
[00400040] 34020004  ori $2, $0, 4            ; 18: li $v0, 4 
[00400044] 3c011001  lui $1, 4097 [output]    ; 19: la $a0, output 
[00400048] 3424001a  ori $4, $1, 26 [output]  
[0040004c] 0000000c  syscall                  ; 20: syscall 
[00400050] 34020001  ori $2, $0, 1            ; 23: li $v0, 1 
[00400054] 00102021  addu $4, $0, $16         ; 24: move $a0, $s0 
[00400058] 0000000c  syscall                  ; 25: syscall 
[0040005c] 3402000a  ori $2, $0, 10           ; 28: li $v0, 10 
[00400060] 0000000c  syscall                  ; 29: syscall 

As with your specific line number 8, there are others in there as well. Interestingly, though the linked documentation states explicitly that it uses andi for the li pseudo instruction, it's clear that it's using ori in this case. As stated, it's irrelevant provided the functional effect is the same (and the documentation I linked to may be a different version). So, I suspect there's no real issue there.

You should not be fooled by the fact that, in the error message, the caret ^ is directly under the $ in $v0. This may lead you to believe that it's an issue with the register name rather than the instruction.
I originally thought it may be the use of a proportional font in the error dialog but I get the same issue under Windows with a fixed size font. But, even when you change $v0 into $2, it still gives the same error if that pseudo instruction aren't enabled:
spim: (parser) syntax error on line 8 of file C:/mipsdev/xyzzy.s
  li $2, 4
     ^


As an aside, I'm well versed with this problem since, until recently, Python was atrocious in where on the line it said an error was, sometimes even flagging it on a different line :-)

By enabling "Accept Pseudo Instructions", the problem disappears for both $2 and $v0.

Also interesting that the OP has the branch-delay slot enabled.  Most MIPS questions on Stack Overflow are about fake / simplified MIPS without a branch-delay slot, like MARS defaults to.  Definitely something to check on when configuring QtSPIM for following examples from a course or something.  (Some assemblers still hide the delay slot for you unless you use .set noreorder; I don't know what QtSPIM does.)
